# Extra rich text options appearing in TinyMCE jQuery package

Tags: javascript, tinymce, richtextbox

I implemented the tinyMCE jQuery package and I got rid of some of the rich-text options because my site didn't need them, but I am still having them appear on the page.

Here is an example where this is occurring: http://www.problemio.com/add_problem.php

I am trying to only have the first row of rich-text options appear, and not sure why the second and third rows appear.  As you can see from the JS I am pasting below, I erased the instructions for the second and third rows to appear, but they still appear:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load jQuery -->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.3");
</script>
-->


<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.problemio.com/js/problemio.js"></script>

<!-- Load jQuery build -->
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
                        // Location of TinyMCE script
                        script_url : '/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                        // General options
                        theme : "advanced",
                        plugins : ",style,advimage,advlink,emotions,paste,",

                        // Theme options
                        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,|,emotions,|,bullist,numlist,|,link,image,",

                        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                        //theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

                        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
                        content_css : "css/content.css",

                        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
                        //template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
                        //external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
                        //external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
                        //media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

                        // Replace values for the template plugin
                        template_replace_values : {
                                username : "Some User",
                                staffid : "991234"
                        }
                });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: i strongly suggest not to use the jQuery tinymce build, because it is far from being fast when processing keyboard input. the build is a source of problems. it is better to load the regular tinymce.js + the regular jquery.js

Comment: @Thariama I actually tried your suggestion first, but I had a problem where the screen would load with the old non-richtext form, and then in 2 seconds load up the rich-text textarea, which made the UX very broken-looking. Do you know of this particular problem? When I googled for solution, I found the fix to be the jQuery package.

Comment: no, i never encountered such a problem

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue so in case anyone else comes across this here is the solution:  http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:theme_advanced_buttons_1_n

You need to add the following lines to the config options:

```
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : ""
```